# Summarised Inside Join with Attribute Criteria using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, select-by-attribute

I have a situation in which I need to find how many points lie within a polygon, this would be quite simple with a summarized inside join from points to polygons except for the fact that the points have a time field and I only need to know only when the "point time" is in-between the "polygon start time field" and the "polygon end time field". Then I need the sum of all those points that meet that criteria and place into a new field of the polygon layer. I have around 3000 points and 2500 polygons (polygons overlap, thus needing the time constraint)

Logic:
SUMofPoints (IF Point is over polygon AND IF Polygon Start Time < Point Time < Polygon End time)

All Point and polygon times are stored in a attribute field inside a geodatabase. If it helps the times are formatted as "yyyymmddhhmm"

I have a feeling that this requires python (or maybe even model builder?) but I have no formal experience in python although I have resources to friends and professors who do. So as simple as possible would be nice, but I know these things aren't really that simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is best suited for a python script, however you could accomplish it without scripting.
As a trade-off, there are a number of steps though...

for simplicity I use integer fields for your time attribute

providing your shape file is not 3D (as this will use a dissolve which may alter Z values) you could try the following steps:

1) add an ID field to your polygon shape file that would store unique polygon IDs. You can calculate them for example, FID + 1

2) use a **spatial join** tool from within Analysis Tools\Overlay\Spatial Join
within spatial join - target features:  polygon, join features: points, join operation:   JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY and match option: COMPLETELY_CONTAINS

3) open attribute table of the shape file obtained from 2) and add a new field. Right click on it and open field calculator. Make sure to select Python parser and check Show Codeblock. Inside Pre-Logic Script Code copy the following (indentation matters!):

```
def CheckIfIDIsWithin (fieldMin,fieldMax, field):
    if field >= fieldMin and field <= fieldMax:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

then in your filed = copy the following
CheckIfIDIsWithin (startID, endID, newfield)
this will assign 1 or -1 based on whether the number falls within the start/end numbers

4) delete all features with newfield = -1

5) use a dissolve tool and for input features: output from 3, for dissolve fields select your unique polygon ID (as added in 1), for statistics field add polygon ID and then for statistic type select COUNT - **this should give you the count of points that are within polygons and are within attribute range**

6) finally join output from 4 with you polygon shape file to get all original attribution back if required

Answer (score 0):

Your Question seems to be quite similar to [How to perform a join on simultaneous spatial and attribute criteria in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43238/how-to-perform-a-join-on-simultaneous-spatial-and-attribute-criteria-in-arcgis/43304#43304) so my Answer is based on the one I provided there.

1. Iterate through each unique time period in your polygons (using ModelBuilder or Python) one at a time to **Select** out your polygons and points for that time period.
2. Run your Spatial Join on each time period's data
3. Append your data for each time period into a dataset for all time periods