# Performing join on simultaneous spatial and attribute criteria in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, spatial-join

I have two point layers and want to perform a spatial join on nearest distance.

Normally it is easy with ArcMap. But now I have a restricting condition on the spatial join. The restriction only allows the attributes to be joined if the nearest point is within the same country.

Both point layers have information about the country in their attribute table (*e.g.*, "de" for Germany). So it must be some spatial join like:

```
Join attribute B to layer A on nearest distance where countryID_Layer A = countryID_Layer B.
```

Does anybody have an idea how I could solve this?

EDIT: Image I have following attributes: Table1(hotels): h_key, l_iso_a2, geom and in Table2(iata_codes): loc, ctry, geom

EDIT2: I tried to write the SQL-Statement, but it does not work somehow. Can anybody help me with this statement?:

```
select distinct on (h.h_key) h.h_key, h.l_iso_a2, i.loc, i.ctry, distance
from ( select h.h_key, h.l_iso_a2, i.loc, i.ctry as country2, st_distance (h.geom,
i.geom) as distance 
from hotels AS h, iata_codes AS i 
where h.l_iso_a2 = i.ctry order by h.geom <-> i.geom ) as iata_codes_h_key;
```

Comment: Are there many countries involved? You could just select one country first and then do the spatial join. Then select other country, etc. If it are many countries this might not be the most efficient solution however.

Comment: Hello Stefan, thanks for your help. But I need to do it for the whole world.

Comment: I thought so... I don't if such a function exists in ArcGIS. If the data was in Postgres I could probably help.

Comment: add a country2 field to data number 2. Then after the spatial join select country <> country2. Delete them.

Comment: Thank you both for your input! I actually decided to put the three layers (point1, point2, poly_world) into a postgres. Now that they are stored in the DB I would appreciate your input to perform the calculation. 

Thanks in advance!
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. This helps:

```
with dist_min as ( 
select h.gid, min(st_distance(h.geom, i.geom)) dist_min from t1 h, t2 i 
where h.country = i.country 
group by h.gid 
) 
select h.attribute1, h.gid, i.attribute1, i.gid, d.dist_min from dist_min d, t1 h, t2 i 
where st_distance(h.geom, i.geom) = dist_min 
order by h.attribute1
```

Comment: Cool! Similar to what I suggested, isn't it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Comment by @Brad Nesom provides an Answer with minimal steps to do what you want but may process a lot of data that gets deleted at the end.

For an alternative with more steps but less processing you could try this:

1. Iterate through your countries (using **ModelBuilder** or **Python**) one at a time to **Select** out your points for that country.
2. Run your **Spatial Join** on each country's data
3. **Append** your data for each country into a whole world dataset

Answer (score 1):

In postgres it would be something like

```
select 
   distinct on (t2.point1_attribute) t2.point1_attribute, t2.country, t2.point2_attribute, t2.country2, t2.distance
from
  (
  select t1.point1_attribute, t1.country, t2.point2_attribute, t2.country as country2, st_distance (t1.geom, t2.geom) as distance
  from poin1 t1, point t2
  where t1.country = t2.country
  order by t1.geom  t2.geom
 ) 
as t2
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Got a question to your SELECT. Aren't there too many t2 in the select-row? I defined the columns in my initial question above. Sorry, I'm a newbie on this area. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried this? It is a select within a select so that is why there are so many t2.

Comment: Hello Stefan, thank you very much. Well, I cannot get it run. I tried this:                                                                           select 
   distinct on (i.gid) i.loc, i.ctry, i.country2, i.distance
from
  (
  select h.h_key, h.l_iso_a2, i.ctry as country2, st_distance (h.geom, i.geom) as distance
  from point hotels, point iata_codes
  where h.l_iso_a2 = i.ctry
  order by h.geom  i.geom
 ) 
as iata_codes

Comment: Maybe you can help me again?

Comment: select distinct on (t2.h_key), t2.h_key, t2.l_iso_a2, t2.country2, t2.distance from (select h.h_key, h.l_iso_a2, i.ctry as country2, st_distance (h.geom, i.geom) as distance from point_hotels h, point_iata_codes i where h.l_iso_a2 = i.ctry order by h.geom igeom) as t2

Comment: Thank you. It says "relation "point_hotels" does not exist" :(

Comment: Enter the correct name of the table there

Comment: It's calculating something. At least since 35 min now. But t1 has about 140.000 rows and t2 12.000. Guess that takes some time, right?

Comment: That might take some time, yes! You could set a limit at the end of the query to see if it is working

Comment: It really takes a lot of time. It's still running. Are there some "tuning" possiblities for the next time?

Comment: select distinct on (t2.h_key) t2.h_key, t2.l_iso_a2, t2.country2, t2.distance 
from (select h.h_key, h.l_iso_a2, i.ctry as country2, st_distance (h.geom, i.geom) as distance 
from hotels h, iata_codes i 
where h.l_iso_a2 = i.ctry 
order by h.geom, i.geom) as t2
limit 2;                                                          This one is running for 30 minutes now (and it is limited to two rows); the one without limiting factor is runnig for five hours now. I have now time reference for calculations like this. is it okay that it's not finished yet?

Comment: That doesn't seems okay. If you send me the files I can have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What would be the best way to send it to you?

Comment: E-mail can be found in my profile

Comment: Sorry, but cannot see it. You could send me an eMail an I'll send you the files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6695/discussion-between-stefan-van-der-hoorn-and-hoge6b01)